# How to prevent user from accessing an action by typing it to address bar?

Tags: web2py

I have a method `potentially_dangerous_method()` in my controller. I don't want the user to have access to it any time, as it does some database record deleting and inserting. I only want another action `bouncer()` (and only that) to call it, and that action has all the proper validations and checks, so it knows the method can really be called.

But as it stands, the user can just type `[application]/[controller]/potentially_dangerous_method` into the address bar to access the method. How can I prevent it?

Comment: Is `bouncer()` part of the same app and the only place that calls `potentially_dangerous_method()`? If so, is there any reason `potentially_dangerous_method()` needs to be an action exposed as an HTTP endpoint (as opposed to a private function accessible internally only)?

Comment: It may not be the only place to call it. But there is no real reason. How can I make it private? Also it's not the only one. I have several methods that are allowed to be accessed only after certain method has done the validation, so keeping my controller/modules clean is also a priority.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `potentially_dangerous_method` does not need to be accessed directly as its own HTTP endpoint, then you can include it in the controller and still make it private by (a) starting its name with a double underscore (i.e., `__potentially_dangerous_method`) or (b) defining it with parameters (e.g., `def potentially_dangerous_method(arg1, arg2):`). See the documentation on [dispatching](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#Dispatching).

Alternatively, you can define such functions in model files or in modules.

Finally, if such functions do need to be accessible directly via HTTP requests, you can protect them via [digitally signed URLs](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#Digitally-signed-urls) using the `@auth.requires_signature()` decorator.